# Mybatis set TypeHandle for Specified field

Tags: mybatis

I'm using mybatis in Java project, I want to set a typeHandle for a blob type column, in this typeHandle, I will thansfer these byte[] in blob to string type, I want just set this typeHandle for this column, but not set this typeHandle default for others, what should I do?

mybatis vesion is 3.4.0;

I have set xml like next:

for query sql:

```xml
<result column="flow_json" property="flowJson" jdbcType="BLOB" javaType="STRING" typeHandler="MyTypeHandle"/>
```

for update or insert sql:

```xml
#{flowJson, typeHandler=MyTypeHandle}
```

When execute select function, it does work fine, only flowJson column call my typeHadle, but, when execute update function, all string type properties call this typeHandle.

```java
@Slf4j
public class FlowBlobTypeHandle extends BaseTypeHandler<String>

    @Override
    public void setNonNullParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i,
                                    String parameter, JdbcType jdbcType) throws SQLException {
        ByteArrayInputStream bis;
        try {
            bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(GzipUtil.compressZip(parameter));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Blob Encoding Error!");
        }
        ps.setBinaryStream(i, bis, parameter.length());
    }

    @Override
    public String getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName)
            throws SQLException {
        Blob blob = rs.getBlob(columnName);
        byte[] returnValue = null;
        String result = null;
        if (null != blob) {
            returnValue = blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());
        }
        try {
            if (null != returnValue) {
                result = new String(GzipUtil.unCompressZip(returnValue));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Blob Encoding Error!");
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String getNullableResult(CallableStatement cs, int columnIndex)
            throws SQLException {
        Blob blob = cs.getBlob(columnIndex);
        byte[] returnValue = null;
        String result = null;
        if (null != blob) {
            returnValue = blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());
        }
        try {
            if (null != returnValue) {
                result = new String(GzipUtil.unCompressZip(returnValue));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Blob Encoding Error!");
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, int columnName) throws SQLException {
        String result = null;
        Blob blob = rs.getBlob(columnName);
        byte[] returnValue = null;
        if (null != blob) {
            returnValue = blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());
        }
        try {
            if (null != returnValue) {
                result = new String(GzipUtil.unCompressZip(returnValue));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Blob Encoding Error!");
        }
        log.debug("exit function");
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is specified in the `typeHandlers` section in the mybatis config?

Comment: I have set  "mybatis:type-handlers-package" property in yml file; @Roman Konoval

Comment: Asking just in case: is this a complete definition of the handler class (that is it has no `@MappedJdbcTypes` defined)? And also are there any inherited classes that have `@MappedJdbcTypes`?

Comment: If there is no `@MappedJdbcTypes` defined on the class or any of it's children then I would set a breakpoint in `setNotNullParameter` and look up the stack to figure out how mybatis decides that this particular handler should be involved. The code of mybatis is rather clear and this analysis would give you a clue and some direction to look to.

Comment: ok, I'll have a try